# ch.write() goes through the whole pipeline

Tags: netty

I have two `SimpleChannelHandler` in my applicaltion:

```
pipeline.addLast("handler1", new FirstHandler());
pipeline.addLast("handler1", new SecondHandler());
```

Both implement the `messageReceived`and the `writeRequested`. The `FirstHandler` is doing some handshaking stuff and will be removed after it's done, such that just the `SecondHandler` stays in the pipe.

If I write something on the channel with `ch.write(...)` in the handshainking step, then it goes goes through the whole pipe (from the last to the first handler). Why is even the `writeRequested` from the `SecondHandler` called? I expected that it's just going back from the layer where we do the ch.write(...):

```
         |                   ^
         v                   |
    FirstHandler ---->  FirstHandler

    // Not used in the handshaking step
    SecondHandler ---->  SecondHandler
```

Why the `ch.write(...)` goes through all layers?

Answer (score 1):

It is because, there are many ways to write from a handler, from channel.write() to directly using the `org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels`class. You have used the channel.write() which actually delegates to first. In your case, you have to directly use second method from Channels.

1. Writing to the last downstream handler in the pipeline

   `public static ChannelFuture write(Channel channel, Object message)..`
2. Writing to the closest downstream handler

   `public static void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelFuture future, Object message)..`

Comment: It looks good. Except that I don't know what to do with the `ChannelFuture`. I am using a `Channels.future(ctx.getChannel())` like in some examples.

Comment: Do nothing with the channel future if you so choose.